# value is invalid for type

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, contract, types

I'm trying to call the [`addLiquidity` entrypoint of this contract](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/entrypoints), which is a copy of the Liquidity Baking CPMM contract, which is itself a copy of the Dexter contract.

[The original Dexter docs give an example of how to call the `addLiquidity` entrypoint](https://gitlab.com/camlcase-dev/dexter/-/blob/master/docs/dexter-cli.md#add-liquidity), and I have been formatting my `tezos-client` command identically.

However when I run that command I get an error telling me that the argument I have passed to the [`addLiquidity` entrypoint](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/entrypoints) is incorrect. This is confusing as I have formatted it the same way as the example in the docs.

Here is the command I"m running:
`tezos-client transfer 10 from alice to KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5 --entrypoint 'addLiquidity'  --arg 'Pair (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0) (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z")' --burn-cap 999`

Here is the error I get:

```
Invalid argument passed to contract KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5.
At (unshown) location 0, value
  (Left (Left (Left (Pair (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0) (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z")))))
is invalid for type
  or (or (or (pair %addLiquidity
                (address %owner)
                (nat %minLqtMinted)
                (nat %maxTokensDeposited)
                (timestamp %deadline))
             (unit %default))
         (or (pair %removeLiquidity
                (address %to)
                (nat %lqtBurned)
                (mutez %minXtzWithdrawn)
                (nat %minTokensWithdrawn)
                (timestamp %deadline))
             (pair %tokenToToken
                (address %outputDexterContract)
                (nat %minTokensBought)
                (address %to)
                (nat %tokensSold)
                (timestamp %deadline))))
     (or (pair %tokenToXtz
            (address %to)
            (nat %tokensSold)
            (mutez %minXtzBought)
            (timestamp %deadline))
         (pair %xtzToToken (address %to) (nat %minTokensBought) (timestamp %deadline))).
At (unshown) location 0, value
  (Left (Left (Pair (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0) (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z"))))
is invalid for type
  or (or (pair %addLiquidity
            (address %owner)
            (nat %minLqtMinted)
            (nat %maxTokensDeposited)
            (timestamp %deadline))
         (unit %default))
     (or (pair %removeLiquidity
            (address %to)
            (nat %lqtBurned)
            (mutez %minXtzWithdrawn)
            (nat %minTokensWithdrawn)
            (timestamp %deadline))
         (pair %tokenToToken
            (address %outputDexterContract)
            (nat %minTokensBought)
            (address %to)
            (nat %tokensSold)
            (timestamp %deadline))).
At (unshown) location 0, value
  (Left (Pair (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0) (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z")))
is invalid for type
  or (pair %addLiquidity
        (address %owner)
        (nat %minLqtMinted)
        (nat %maxTokensDeposited)
        (timestamp %deadline))
     (unit %default).
At (unshown) location 0, value
  (Pair (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0) (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z"))
is invalid for type
  pair (address %owner)
       (nat %minLqtMinted)
       (nat %maxTokensDeposited)
       (timestamp %deadline).
At (unshown) location 1, value
  (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 0)
is invalid for type address.
At (unshown) location 1, unexpected primitive, only a string or a byte
sequence can be used here.
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the explorer](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/entrypoints), the `addLiquidity` entrypoint accepts parameter of type

```
(pair address (pair nat (pair nat timestamp))
```

But you pass (according to [the original Dexter contract](https://tzkt.io/KT1BGQR7t4izzKZ7eRodKWTodAsM23P38v7N/entrypoints)):

```
(pair (pair address nat) (pair nat timestamp))
```

These are two different types, so you need to re-group your `Pair`s this way:

```
Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" (Pair 0 (Pair 100 "2030-06-29T18:00:21Z"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is incredibly helpful. I've looked around for a really good explanation of pairs and I have yet to find one. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Whirlybird not sure if I have ever seen such the explanation. `pair` is quite self-explanatory :) Maybe this will help: https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#type-pair